# How to number all records with the same ID in ACCESS 2010 SQL without using Macros?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I got a Access 2010 SQL query, which has the following result:

```
ID -- Name  --- description
1 --- Bild1 --- Text1 
1 --- Bild2 --- Text2 
2 --- Bild3 --- Text3 
2 --- Bild4 --- Text4
2 --- Bild5 --- Text5
3 --- Bild2 --- Text6 
4 --- Bild3 --- Text7
```

Now I want to improve the SQL query, that all rows with the same ID will be numbered.
The result should look like this:

```
ID -- Name  --- description --- Number
1 --- Bild1 --- Text1 --- 1 
1 --- Bild2 --- Text2 --- 2 
2 --- Bild3 --- Text3 --- 1 
2 --- Bild4 --- Text4 --- 2 
2 --- Bild5 --- Text5 --- 3 
3 --- Bild2 --- Text6 --- 1 
4 --- Bild3 --- Text7 --- 1
```

How can I do that? A RowNumber() function does not exist in ACCESS, I will use this in query in word, so I can't use Macros at all and DCount does not provide the correct results.

Thanks for your help.

Oliver

Edit:
The actual query is a bit complicated, therefore I tried to make it a bit easier.

The query:

```
SELECT g1.akt.KraftAspektID, (
        SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM GesamtKraftAbfrage2 g2 
        WHERE (g1.akt.KraftAspektID = g2.akt.KraftAspektID) 
          AND (g1.Wirkung <=g2.Wirkung)
    ) AS RowNo
FROM GesamtKraftAbfrage2 AS g1
ORDER BY g1.ka.Name;
```

GesamtKraftAbfrage2 is:
SELECT ka.ID AS ID, ka.Name, ka.beschreibung, k.Bildname, k.Bild, ka.MindestkraftLevel, ka.MaximumLevel, kart.Name, k.Name, aazi.Name AS Primärart, aazi2.Name AS Sekundärart, akt.*, kt.*, va.VerteidigungText, wt.*, wu.Name AS Wuefelname, DCount("[nummer]","[GesamtKraftAbfrage2]","[nummer]<=" & [nummer]) AS Reihe
FROM ((((((((Kraftaspekt AS ka INNER JOIN Kraft AS k ON k.ID = ka.KraftID) INNER JOIN Kraftart AS kart ON kart.ID = ka.KraftArtID) INNER JOIN AspektArtZusaetze AS aazi ON aazi.ID = ka.AspektartZusatzID) LEFT JOIN AspektArtZusaetze AS aazi2 ON aazi2.ID = ka.SekundaereAspektArtID) LEFT JOIN AktionskostenTransformation AS akt ON akt.KraftaspektID = ka.ID) LEFT JOIN KostenTransformation AS kt ON kt.KraftaspektID = ka.ID) LEFT JOIN VerteidigungAbfrage AS va ON va.KraftaspektID = ka.ID) LEFT JOIN KraftAspektWirkung AS wt ON wt.KraftaspektID = ka.ID) LEFT JOIN Wuerfel AS wu ON wt.WuerfelID = wu.ID;

and there are many more querys related on that.... I cannot post them all here.
Perhaps just the columns of the Output of GesamtKraftAbfrage2:

```
ID  
ka.Name  
beschreibung  
Bildname    
Bild    
MindestkraftLevel   
MaximumLevel    
kart.Name   
k.Name  
Primärart   
Sekundärart 
akt.KraftAspektID   
akt.Name    
Bewegung    
wt.KraftAspektID    
Anzahl  
WuerfelID   
Wirkung 
Wuefelname
```

Comment: You must put `Name` into square brackets: `[Name]`. Not sure if this is the only problem - if not, please post the error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can readily think of in MS Access is a correlated subquery:

```
select q.*,
       (select count(*)
        from q as q2
        where q2.id = q.id and q2.name <= q.name
       ) as Number
from q
order by id, name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The answers are almost the same and I tried that before :-) My Problem is that I cant get access on the outer select. I get the error message: "q.ID is not a valid field Name of Expression". When I test it with hard coded values like "where q2.id = 2 and q2.name <= "") I got no error. Any ideas?

Comment: @KohlanDerBarbar: Please edit your question and post the *actual* query you tried, and the *actual* field names. Because e.g. if there is really a field "name", you need to put it into [square brackets] because it's a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT ID, Name, description,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
        FROM mytable AS t2
        WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t1.Name > t2.Name)
FROM mytable AS t1
ORDER BY ID, Name
```