# horizontal to vertical access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

im having trouble with SQL query (MICROSOFT ACCESS) that involves converting horizontal rows to vertical rows

Below is my data
ORIGINAL:

```
MAIN_ID | SECOND_ID  
101 |   301    
102 |   302  
104 |   304  
101 |   311  
101 |   321
```

OUTPUT:

```
MAIN_ID | SECOND_ID1 | SECOND_ID2 | SECOND_ID3  
101     |   301      |      311   | 321  
102     |   302  
104     |   304
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE :)

Comment: Run the crosstab query wizard.

Comment: it will say that I don't have enough field as it requires 3 or more field.

Comment: Heh, that's right. If you want to do it with a SQL query, your column headings `SECOND_ID1 | SECOND_ID2 | SECOND_ID3` need to come from somewhere, Access can't just create them out of thin air.

Comment: You can try using something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36548613/3820271  as input for the crosstab query.

Comment: tried em, and it works having another column counter after it.. but I have another problem to get the counter to be the header of the table. is my query correct? 
TRANSFORM First(A.SECOND_ID)
SELECT A.MAIN_ID
FROM A
GROUP BY A.MAIN_ID
PIVOT A.COUNTER;
keep getting Microsoft access doesn't recognize MAIN_ID from other table